# How to mount a samba share on non-standard port?

Tags: windows, networking, samba, smb, cifs

The firewall on my network drops all packets on TCP port 139 and 445. So all samba shares don't work outside the LAN.

I tried letting the samba daemon listen on a non-standard port. This method works well for linux, because both `smbclient` and `smbmount` has an option to set server port. But on windows I cannot find a similar option.

Does Windows support mounting smb shares on non-standard ports? Third-party softwares are also acceptable.

---

Edit:

`\\hostname:port\share` in Windows explorer doesn't work. Strangely, I can see the connection is established on the server. But Windows keeps telling me that the server couldn't be reached. It doesn't work even in LAN with standard port 445, in which case a path without port number will get through.

Comment: Have you tried setting the port in the url? `smb://myhost:555/my/path/to/share`

Comment: @Gjordis: Yes and it fails. See my edit.

Comment: In your case I would use a port redirector running on my local 127.0.0.1:139 and on 127.0.0.1:445, and I would redirect them to your destination ip. But I think a VPN solution would be more feasible (for example, openvpn).

Answer (score 5):

This is possible! It's been a good few years, but combining a [loopback interface tutorial I found](https://gbe0.com/posts/windows/server-windows/create-loopback-interface-with-powershell/) with *portions* out of @Mike's [..link-only] answer (multihost version) I've created a script that can do this for you.

[**You can use this**](https://gist.github.com/Hashbrown777/081e57ff9673a1f457e1c3a71b55cfaf#file-attachsmb-ps1-L61) after running `Install-Module -Name LoopbackAdapter -MinimumVersion 1.2.0.0` in an admin terminal (dont forget to dot-source the script so you can call this).

```powershell
Create-Host -Name bob -Ip 10.254.0.1 -Dest ipOfHostname -Port port
```

which [upon reboot] will allow you to go to `\\bob` (fake IP 10.254.0.1) which attaches to your "hostname:port" from your question.
This will persist across boots and you don't need to re-run it if the source server goes up or down; teardown is as simple as `Retire-Host -Name bob`.

**That easy, one command, programmatic, no gui/windows settings dialogs**; but feel free to follow along below manually.

---

**Explanation:**

Use `netsh portproxy` to link a fake IP with your SMB server, this will make the nonstandard port accessible on one Explorer accepts.

```powershell
#it's important IP's are used here, not hostnames
netsh `
    interface portproxy `
    add       v4tov4 `
    listenaddress=<#fakeIP#> `
    listenport=445 `
    connectaddress=<#serverIP#> `
    connectport=<#serverPort#>
```

Optionally add the IP to your `%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file so you don't need to remember this IP (Eg interact with `\\bob` instead of `\\10.254.0.1`).

Use [DevCon](https://github.com/PlagueHO/LoopbackAdapter) to create a loopback network adapter, this "network" is what will host the IP.

```powershell
$interface = New-LoopbackAdapter -Name <#NAME#>
```

Disable conflicting/unused services that break various things.

```powershell
$interface `
| Disable-NetAdapterBinding `
    -ComponentID ms_msclient,ms_pacer,ms_server,ms_lltdio,ms_rspndr

$interface `
| Set-DnsClient `
    -RegisterThisConnectionsAddress $False `
    -PassThru `
| Set-NetIPInterface `
    -InterfaceMetric '254' `
    -WeakHostSend    Enabled `
    -WeakHostReceive Enabled `
    -Dhcp Disabled
```

Set the IP your machine will be reachable at on this "network".

```powershell
$interface `
| New-NetIPAddress `
    -IPAddress     <#fakeIP#> `
    -PrefixLength  32 `
    -AddressFamily IPv4
```

Done! Upon reboot the forwarding will have hooked up, and you can access it as long as your pc can access the remote port. The setup will not disappear until you manually tear it down.

---

It's worth noting I only forward to 445 (and actually from 445 using `ssh -L` tunnelling to a machine on a network my pc cannot directly see), but it will simply be a change/additional `netsh portproxy` to swap/add the 139 equivalent if wanted.

To troubleshoot you can check windows is attempting to forward using

```powershell
netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4
```

whether that is successfully listening on the loopback device

```powershell
netstat -an | sls ':445'
```

and if your remote machine's server is accepting connections

```powershell
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName <#serverIP#> -Port <#serverPort#>
```

finally that the whole thing has come together (and maybe it's some credential issue)

```powershell
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName <#fakeIP#> -Port 445
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible as windows does only support ports 445 and 139

You might be able to use ssh tunneling. Here is a reference using windows and linux: https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~xuanluo/sshproxywin.html

Comment: Do you have a reference for the claim that Windows only supports 445 and 139?  I don't doubt it, but it would be nice to see something official, if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still looking for a way to mount SMB resources on a non-standard port, [here](https://www.nikhef.nl/%7Ejanjust/CifsOverSSH/Win10Loopback.html) is a great article on how to do this. I personally set up `stunnel` to wrap SMB traffic with SSL, since I access my SMB shares remotely over the Internet. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If third-party tools are OK and you only need to access a SMB share and not really mount it to an drive letter, the tool [Owlfiles](https://www.skyjos.com/owlfiles/) does the job. Here you can enter a different port number for accessing SMB shares.

I started to use it when tunneling SMB through SSH so I do not need to setup a loopback adapter.

The tool is available through MS store and the feature is available in the free version of this tool.